# Align multiple labels based on width

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a composable where a list of labels with a description are displayed. I want the labels to be all of the same width (the width of the widest label), with the description shifted to the right so that they all start at the same offset. The labels and the description also need to be baseline aligned.

I can achieve this with a ConstraintLayout using barriers, but I'm trying to figure out a solution without ConstraintLayout.

What I have so far is this

```
@Composable
fun CityCard(
    city: CityResultModel,
    onClick: (CityResultModel) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Card(modifier = modifier.clickable(onClick = { onClick(city) })) {
        Column {
            Row {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.city_result_label),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                    modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline(),
                )
                Text(
                    text = city.name.toString(),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                )
            }
            Row {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.country_result_label),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                    modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline(),
                )
                Text(
                    text = city.country.toString(),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                )
            }
            Row {
                Text(
                    text = stringResource(R.string.coordinates_result_label),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                    modifier = Modifier.alignByBaseline(),
                )
                Text(
                    text = city.coordinates.toString(),
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which renders like this

[image: current]

but what I'm after is this

[image: expected]

How can I get the expected alignment?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most efficient solution, but solves the problem. There certainly are better solutions, the baseline alignment here is not perfect.

```
@Composable
private fun City(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
        Layout(
            content = content,
            modifier = modifier,
        ) { measurables, constraints ->
            val looseConstraints = constraints.copy(
                minWidth = 0,
                minHeight = 0,
            )
            val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
                measurable.measure(looseConstraints)
            }
            val labels = List(placeables.size / 2) { index ->
                placeables[2 * index]
            }
            val descriptions = List(placeables.size / 2) { index ->
                placeables[2 * index + 1]
            }
            val maxLabelWidth = labels.maxByOrNull { it.width }?.width ?: 0
            val width = List(labels.size) { index ->
                maxLabelWidth + descriptions[index].width
            }.maxOrNull() ?: 0
            val height = List(labels.size) { index ->
                max(labels[index].height, descriptions[index].height)
            }.sum()
            layout(
                width.coerceAtMost(constraints.maxWidth),
                height.coerceAtMost(constraints.maxHeight)
            ) {
                var yPosition = 0

                for (i in labels.indices) {
                    val label = labels[i]
                    val description = descriptions[i]
                    val labelHeight = label.height
                    val descriptionHeight = description.height
                    label.place(
                        x = 0,
                        y = yPosition + (descriptionHeight - labelHeight).coerceAtLeast(0)
                    )
                    description.place(
                        x = maxLabelWidth,
                        y = yPosition + (labelHeight - descriptionHeight).coerceAtLeast(0)
                    )
                    yPosition += label.height.coerceAtLeast(description.height)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be:

```
Card(modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {  })
) {
    Row(Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
        Column(Modifier.padding(horizontal = 4.dp)) {
            Row () {
                Text(
                    text = "City",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                )
            }
            Row (){
                Text(
                    text = "Country",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                )
            }
            Row() {
                Text(
                    text = "Coordinates",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                )
            }
        }
        Column(Modifier.padding(horizontal = 4.dp)) {
            Row() {
                Text(
                    text = "London",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
            }
            Row() {
                Text(
                    text = "UK",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
            }
            Row() {
                Text(
                    text = "Lat xx.xx Lon -120",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried something like this earlier, but this seems to work well only if the text size for the label and the description is the same, otherwise it gets out of alignment.

Comment: @Francesc You are right, your answer is good. Also check the "old" implementation of DataTable: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/3c41ab106ef3c2894c78ac53db004fd74365b21b/ui/ui-material/src/main/java/androidx/ui/material/DataTable.kt#L459